# Sentence formatting

Tags: java, strings, formatting

I wrote this function to format a given sentence via Java, and I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this without use of external libraries, such as with regex.

```
public class ChatFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "hello, it's a monday today and i think i'll go to the store. and get? some! tea.";
        System.out.println(optimizeText(input));
    }

    public static String optimizeText(String text) {
        char buf[] = text.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        boolean endMarker = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            char c = buf[i];
            if (endMarker && c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                buf[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
                endMarker = false;
            }
            if (c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?')
                endMarker = true;
            if (c == 'i') {
                char next = 0;
                if (i + 1 < buf.length) {
                    next = buf[i + 1];
                }
                char last = 0;
                if (i - 1 > 0)
                    last = buf[i - 1];
                if (last == ' ' && (next == ' ' || next == '\'' || next == 0))
                    buf[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c);
            }
        }
        return new String(buf, 0, buf.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Inconsistent braces usage**

Some of your `if` statements have enclosing `{ }` but some do not, please standardize and use them throughout. :)

2. **Character comparison**

`c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'` can be better represented as `Character.isLetter(c)`. IMHO it's easier to comprehend.

Similarly, `last == ' '` and `next == ' '` can be replaced with `Character.isWhitespace(last)` and `Character.isWhitespace(next)` respectively.

3. **Derivation of `next` and `last` characters when encountering the letter `'i'`**

I'll prefer to use the ternary operator to set `next` and `last` as such, it's a little more compact:

```
char next = i < buf.length - 1 ? buf[i + 1] : 0;
char last = i > 1 ? buf[i - 1] : 0;
```

4. **`If-else-if` ladder**

Since your three `if` conditions are mutually exclusive, you can also consider putting them together in one `if-else-if` ladder, e.g.

```
if (endMarker && Character.isLetter(c)) {
    ...
} else if (c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?') {
    ...
} else if (c == 'i') {
    ...
}
```

5. **Use of `toLowerCase()`**

Since you are already operating on a character array, perhaps you can consider converting to lower case letter as the final `else` branch, i.e.

```
char buf[] = text.toCharArray();
...
(for loop)
    if (...) {
        ...
    } else if (c == 'i') {
        ...
    } else {
        buf[i] = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    }
```

This does save one extra copy of the `String` in lower case, if anything.

6. **Testing**

It's fine so far to showcase one example using `public static void main`, but do consider building out some unit tests using a unit testing framework (e.g. TestNG, JUnit):

```
@Test // TestNG
public void doTest() {
    // Hamcrest matchers
    assertThat(optimizeText("that is its"), equalTo("That is its")); 
    assertThat(optimizeText("i'm"), equalTo("I'm"));
}
```

7. **Other notes**

Your simplified logic doesn't appear to handle sentence *structures* accurately, but since you seem to be more concerned with the formatting (capitalization), then I guess it's ok.

Comment: Very well explained answer. Thanks for this!

Comment: @JonathanBeaudoin glad to help!